# Find the number of members of chess club

Tags: combinatorics

The members of a chess club took part in Round Robin competition in which each plays everyone else once. All members scored the same number of points, except 4 juniors whose total score were 17.5. How many members  were there in the club? Assume that for each win a player scores 1 point,  for draw 1/2 point and zero for losing.

Attempt:-
The total no. of games= C(n,2) . n being no. of members.
Every game leads to the business of 1 point, Hence sum of points of every member = C(n,2).
Total points must remain conserved => C(n,2) = 17.5 + points scored by seniors in terms of n .
I m not able to think upon "points scored by seniors in terms of n".
Also i m unable to use the fact that the points of seniors are equal.

Answer=27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there are $s$ seniors with $m/2$ points each.
What is $n$ in terms of $s$?

You should get an equation in integers that involves $s$ and $m$.

Comment: n-4=s. sm/2= C(n,2)-17.5

Comment: Do you know a formula for $C(n,2)$?

Comment: n(n-1)/2, what do we mean by formula

Comment: Yes.  Now, to replace $n$ by a function of $s$.  But I'm going home now.

Comment: But that function contains m

Answer (score 0):

Building on the hints and terminology of @Michael we can write$$\frac{(s+4)(s+3)}{2}=\frac{sm}{2}+17.5$$
or $$s^2+(7-m)s-23=0$$
or $$s=\frac 1 2 ((m-7)\pm \sqrt{m^2-14m+141})$$
The problem then becomes finding a whole number $m$ which gives a whole number solution for $s$. I don't know what method @Michael envisioned for solving this, but brute force computation quickly gives the answer $$m=29$$ 
resulting in $$s=23$$
and hence $$n=27$$

Comment: From your second equation, $s$ is a factor of $23$